# OCR capture2text desde PYTHON

Tags: python, imagen, text, ocr

Tengo la siguiente librería, [capture2text](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/#command_line), que me permite transcribir de imagen a texto.

La estoy utilizando por medio de la consola con el siguiente comando:

```
Capture2Text_CLI.exe -image <file>
```

Y funciona perfectamente, me gustaría utilizarla desde python.

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola Andres, mirate el módulo [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) de la stdlib

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla, funciona perfectamente, dejo el código por si alguien lo necesita:

Answer (score 2):

Con el el módulo [**`subprocess`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) de la **`stdlib`** encontre una solución:

Dejo el código:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run(["path/Capture2Text/Capture2Text_CLI.exe",'--image','myImage'],check=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.stdout
```

Comment: Hola orlando sabes como puedo pasarle una imagen a capture2Text directamente desde python, es decir no pasarle una ruta si no un objeto PilImage, si lo hago como te muestro a continuación me sale error: "process = subprocess.run(["path/Capture2Text/Capture2Text_CLI.exe",'--image',Pil.Image],check=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)"